# How to use d3.js Hierarchy with custom data structure?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been attempting to load a small dataset into d3.js for use with some other d3 aspects. It only has a depth of two, but I'm struggling to get D3 to load it properly. I've tried the following, which in my mind should work?

```
let hierarchy = d3
  .hierarchy()
  .children(d => d.foods)
  .sum(d => d.total)
```

The data sample in question is:

```
let data = {
'SetA': {
    foods: [
        { food: 'Apple', total: 1 },
        { food: 'Banana', total: 1 },
        { food: 'Orange', total: 3 }
    ], label: 'fruits', size: 3
},
'SetB': {
    foods: [
        { food: 'Potato', total: 2 },
        { food: 'Carrot', total: 4 }
    ], label: 'vegetables', size: 2
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to name and organize your data following what `d3.hierarchy` is expecting, look at [documentation here](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#hierarchy)

> The returned node and each descendant has the following properties:
>
> ```
> node.data - the associated data, as specified to the constructor.
> node.depth - zero for the root node, and increasing by one for each descendant generation.
> node.height - zero for leaf nodes, and the greatest distance from any descendant leaf for internal nodes.
> node.parent - the parent node, or null for the root node.
> node.children - an array of child nodes, if any; undefined for leaf nodes.
> node.value - the summed value of the node and its descendants; optional, see node.sum and node.count.
> ```

So your data should be like:

```
let data = {
name: 'root',
children: [{
 name: 'foods A',
 children: [
   {
    name: 'fruits',
    children: [
        { name: 'Apple', size: 1 },
        { name: 'Banana', size: 1 },
        { name: 'Orange', size: 3 },
    ],
  label: 'fruits',
  size: 3,
}]},
{
name: 'foods B',
children: [
  {
    name: 'vegetables',
    children: [
        { name: 'Potato', size: 2 },
        { name: 'Carrot', size: 4 }
    ],
    label: 'vegetables',
    size: 2
 }]
}]
}
```